# run commands as administrator with conditions with specifications

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I wanted to run this `cmd` command as administrator

```
sleep -m 500
```

So I used this command.

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process sleep.exe -m 500 -Verb runas"
```

Error appeared:

```
Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'm'.
At line:1 char:47
+ Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\sleep.exe -m <<<<  500 -Verb runas
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Then, I used this command

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process 'sleep.exe -m 500' -Verb runas"
```

Error appeared:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: The system cannot find
the file specified.
At line:1 char:14
+ Start-Process <<<<  'C:\Windows\System32\sleep.exe -m 500' -Verb runas
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Then, I used this:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process sleep.exe /m 500 -Verb runas"
```

Error appeared:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '500'.
At line:1 char:14
+ Start-Process <<<<  C:\Windows\System32\sleep.exe /m 500 -Verb runas
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Can anyone tell me the correct command for it? I want it to be on batch version.

Comment: `powershell help start-process`

Comment: Powershell and batch are completely different languages

Comment: Yes I know, I just can't figure it out how can I run `sleep -m 500` as administrator using powershell.. Yea, I know how to run it as admin by using `-verb runas` but how can I do the command I want to run (`sleep -m 500`)?

Comment: That's all I need then problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The command is this:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\sleep.exe -ArgumentList -m,500"
```

Comment: Thanks, ACatInLove for making me see `powershell help start-process` :P

Comment: If you're looking for a more PowerShell native function, use `Start-Sleep`

Comment: nope I want it for any program :)